# Change visibility of textView on AlertDialog positive button

Tags: android, listview, dialog, textview, visibility

ok so i didn't have enough room in title to explain this but I have a ListView with a custom adapter, and in the child Views I have a textview. I'm trying to change the visibility of that textview when I show an alert dialog and the positive button is clicked, and my code isn't changing the visibility.

```
    alert.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    EditText editMsg = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editMsg);
                    String msg = editMsg.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (!msg.isEmpty()) {
                        // show message test
                        if (name.equals("Contact 0")) {
                            View v = listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);
                            TextView tvMsg = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg);
                            tvMsg.setText(msg);
                            tvMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Yes the code is getting executed correctly, and yes i've tried doing setText and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged, then changing visibility in adapter.getView if getText > 0

It seems everything is right, its the v is the correct view, i can read other child views to confirm its right, setText is working but setVisibility is not? Why can't I change the visibility?

Comment: What exactly the problem?? Is your text is now visible or else//

Comment: First, check your text color and listview background color are different..

Comment: The problem is it won't become visible. The colors are not issue. Appreciate the response though.

Comment: You have to `setVisibility()` in adapter's `getView()`.

Comment: I've tried that (as mentioned). I'm also able to change the visibilty of a linearlayout in the child view in the list view.onitemclicked event... I'm totally confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. Seems the issue is in calling listView.getAdapter().getView().

replaced with listView.getChildAt(int pos) and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Because, when adapter called the xml file is initialize again and may be the **TextView** is hidden in your xml file. So, my suggestion is:

put a global variable, let say it **global_var**;

write following code into your adapter getView() method.

```
if(global_var){
    tvMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else{
    tvMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

And in this code:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    EditText editMsg = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editMsg);
                    String msg = editMsg.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (!msg.isEmpty()) {
                        // show message test
                        if (name.equals("Contact 0")) {
                            .....
                            .....
                            global_var = true// or something;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

and finally call this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think this will work..

Comment: I've tried this. Does not work. I forget to mention that I'm trying to overlay this textview over an image view, in a relative layout. Maybe that's the issue, will do more testing today.